# full-calendar-scheduler to cant added separate rooms

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Im used my University project for  [full-calendar](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/releases) , Calendar is working fine, but I have some issue ,I want to know how to added some Rooms (Look my attached image)  Im try to added but it's overlap , please help me to fix it 
[image]
Im added  `resourceLabelText: 'Rooms2',` not display  ,look Im draw my issue in Attached image
This is my code

```
 <script>

    $(function() { // document ready

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            now: '2017-12',
            editable: true, // enable draggable events
            aspectRatio: 1.8,
            scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
            header: {
                left: 'today prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timelineThreeDays'
            },
            defaultView: 'timelineThreeDays',
            views: {
                timelineThreeDays: {
                    type: 'timeline',
                    duration: { days: 31 }
                }
            },
            resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',

            resources: [
                { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
                { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' },
                { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange' },
                { id: 'd', title: 'Auditorium D', children: [

                ] },
                { id: 'e', title: 'Auditorium E' },
                { id: 'f', title: 'Auditorium F', eventColor: 'red' },
                { id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G' },
                { id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H' },

            ],
            events: [

                // background event, associated with a resource
                //{ id: 'bg1', resourceId: 'b', rendering: 'background', start: '2017-11-07', end: '2017-11-10' },

                // background event, NOT associated with a resource
                //{ id: 'bg2', rendering: 'background', start: '2017-11-07', end: '2017-11-07' },

                // normal events...
                { id: '6', resourceId: 'g', start: '2017-11-07', end: '2017-11-08', title: 'event 1' },
                { id: '7', resourceId: 'h', start: '2017-11-09', end: '2017-11-12', title: 'event 2' },
                { id: '8', resourceId: 'i', start: '2017-11-11', end: '2017-11-15', title: 'event 3' },
                { id: '9', resourceId: 'j', start: '2017-11-17', end: '2017-11-19', title: 'event 4' },
                { id: '10', resourceId: 'k', start: '2017-11-27', end: '2017-11-28', title: 'event 5' }
            ],
            resourceLabelText: 'Rooms2',

            resources: [
                { id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G' },
                { id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H', eventColor: 'green' },
                { id: 'i', title: 'Auditorium I', eventColor: 'orange' },
                { id: 'j', title: 'Auditorium J', children: [

                ] },
                { id: 'e', title: 'Auditorium E' },
                { id: 'f', title: 'Auditorium F', eventColor: 'red' },
                { id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G' },
                { id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H' },

            ],
            events: [

                // background event, associated with a resource
                //{ id: 'bg1', resourceId: 'b', rendering: 'background', start: '2017-11-07', end: '2017-11-10' },

                // background event, NOT associated with a resource
                //{ id: 'bg2', rendering: 'background', start: '2017-11-07', end: '2017-11-07' },

                // normal events...
                { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2017-11-07', end: '2017-11-08', title: 'event 1' },
                { id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2017-11-09', end: '2017-11-12', title: 'event 2' },
                { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2017-11-11', end: '2017-11-15', title: 'event 3' },
                { id: '4', resourceId: 'e', start: '2017-11-17', end: '2017-11-19', title: 'event 4' },
                { id: '5', resourceId: 'f', start: '2017-11-27', end: '2017-11-28', title: 'event 5' }
            ]





        });


    });

</script>
```

Comment: you appear to be defining "events" and "resources" and "resourceLabelText" twice. I'm pretty sure this won't work properly. FullCalendar expects each option to be defined once, otherwise it won't know which version to use. You also seem to have defined some of the resources (e.g. "g" and "h") multiple times. The IDs need to be unique, otherwise fullCalendar will not know which resource is which when adding events. If you want to split them into two sections (e.g. rooms and rooms2), use resource grouping (see demo at https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.9.0/demos/grouping.html)

Comment: @ADyson Sir,It's work for me,  again Thanks for the link